# Organizar json com Eloquent

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-eloquent, framework

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: quero organizar meu `json` para que eu consulte a tabela **Animal** e **Fazenda**, mas organizadamente, exemplo:

```
{
"animais": {
    "id": 1,
    "nome": "Mimosa",
    "data_nascimento": "2017-04-11 00:00:00",
    "codigo_brinco": "Não informado",
    "codigo_raca": "Não informado",
    "status": 1,
    "data_alteracao": "2018-02-13 00:00:00",
    "data_cadastro": "2018-02-13 00:00:00",
    "usuario_cadastro": 1,
    "usuario_alteracao": null,
    "fazendas_id": 1,
    "lotes_id": 1,
    "fazenda": {
        "id": 1,
        "nome": "Fazenda Nossa Senhora aparecida",
        "data_alteracao": "2018-02-13 00:00:00",
        "data_cadastro": "2018-02-13 00:00:00",
        "usuario_cadastro": 1,
        "usuario_alteracao": "1",
        "status": 1
    }
}
```

Observe que, tem um atributo do `json` chamado "fazenda" que é outra tabela, mas eu não consigo fazer deste modo sem ser pelo `find($id)` do Eloquent teria outro modo de fazer tal coisa ?

Comment: Eu não entendi o que você quer fazer?

Comment: Então, eu queria fazer uma consulta na tabela Animais, que por sua vez, tem relação one to many com a tabela Fazendas, eu queria "mesclar" as consultas para retornar um JSON/Array no formato dado acima.

Comment: Utilize `with` e especifique o nome da relação. !!! entendeu? `Animal::with('fazenda')->get()`

Comment: Entendi sim, e aliás, consegui. Fiz tanta tempestade em copo d'água e no final era só isso. Muitíssimo obrigado!